# Running a loop function , with date timestamp on the file name

Tags: python, loops, iteration

I have a internal function that take sample and target and configuration files and returns 2 csv statistics_df and summary_df.

Target and file_config are fixed but I like to run it for 10 dat files with names like this '20190602test.dat' , '20190603test.dat' , '20190604test.dat' etc. I am trying to make a time range loop but couldn't make it

here is my script for only one file --  It is working

```
target=pd.read_csv('es18.csv')
sample=pd.read_csv('20190602test.dat')

wgt = bp.IPF(sample, target, file_config )
wgt.run()
```

How can I make a date_range based on file name `date_range = []`to be able to run my function like this

for current_date in date_range:
    print(current_date)

```
# run my function
pr = bp.IPF(sample_20190602.dat (or sample_20190603.dat) , # here I just thinking it should be like this
                       target, file_config)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use rrule to iterate over days:

```
import datetime
from dateutil.rrule import rrule, DAILY
start = datetime.datetime(year=2019, month=6, day=1)
end = datetime.datetime(year=2019, month=6, day=10)
for date in rrule(DAILY, dtstart=start, until=end):
    #run your function here
```